# Angular post request runs twice when calling api on node server

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a http post request but it gets fired twice when i call the api.

Basically i know that node is asynchronous so might be waiting to run the sql to get the data but not sure how i can get around it. My code is as follows:

```
$http({ method: 'POST',
                            url: '/api/updateBooking',
                            data: JSON.stringify({'booking' : selectedItem }),
                            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                       if (data == "true")
                       {

                           $scope.updateSuccess = true;
                                                     }
                    }).
                        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        //hits this when unauthorized.
                        $scope.invalid = true;
                    });
```

So as soon as the above code is run it will go straight to the success and then the error but no data being returned. But immediately after it passes the data through.

My server code is below which gets called

a

```
pp.post('/api/updateBooking', function(req,res)
{
     var booking = req.body.booking;
     var success = "false";

     console.log("req.booking=", booking.Date1);

     // just update the booking regardless as the booking is selected and is valid.
     console.log(booking);

     var bookingSql = 'SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE ' + booking.BookingID + '= ID ';

     connection.query(bookingSql, function(err,result){
        console.log(err);
        if(err) {success= false;}
        console.log('here result=', result);
        //if record found then ok to proceed
        if (result != null)
        {
            var updateBookingSQL = 'UPDATE Booking SET ? WHERE ID = ? ';
            var bookingFields  = {  Date1: booking.Date1,
                Date1AMPM: booking.Date1AMPM,
                Date2: moment(booking.date2).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                Date2AMPM: booking.Date2AMPM,
                 }


            console.log('booking fields', bookingFields);

            //go and do the update using the bookingID
            connection.query(updateBookingSQL, [bookingFields, booking.BookingID], function(err,result)
            {
                console.log(err);
                if (err) {success="false";}

                if (result != null)
                {
                    console.log('update booking result', result);
                    if (result.changedRows == 1)
                    {
                        console.log('changed row', result.changedRows);
                        success = "true";

                    }

                }
                res.send(success);
                console.log('result of update====', success);
            });

        }

     });
     console.log('success=', success) ;

});
```

Any ideas would be great

Comment: How do you call that $http? Are you sure it's not being triggered twice?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "fired twice"? Do you mean the `$http POST` is being called twice? Or do you notice two POSTs being sent to your server, even though you only expect the browser to make a single one?

Comment: Just once when I click the button

Comment: Yup http request is called twice

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of problems I see:

1. You should not be concatenating user-inputted values into your SQL query like that (specifically `bookingSql` here), you're open to an SQL injection attack that way.
2. You aren't responding to the POST request when errors occur (specifically after the first query).

Comment: Hi Cheers for the feedback .in regards to the sql i have only put it there temporarily as I intend to create a seperate library which will be calling stored procedures instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the meaning of success from a **boolean** to a **string**. You initialize it to `"false"`, and then on error set it to `false`

Also, you have many control paths in your code which will end up not sending a response to the POST from the client. It is typically good practice to do a response.end() when you are sure  you are done sending stuff back.

Comment: i believe res.send runs the res.end. I had a look in the expressjs code and it states this.end()

Comment: Right, but you have control paths in your POST handler which do not return anything to the requestor, hence adding the response.end() :)

Comment: So where ever I do a res.send I need to add res.end?

Comment: Oh not quite, I meant that you have failure handling cases (potentially) which never `send()` or `end()` the response - right? For those cases, it is probably prudent to do so.